# How to call API Hooks or Call back function from JIRA to DocuSign and revert from DocuSign to JIRA

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Hi guys I am working on one service desk of JIRA, From here I need to pass some information to DocuSign when a button is clicked and a PDF will be generated to DocuSign and it will revert that PDF file to JIRA and that file will be linked to JIRA. If these didn't work directly then any intermediate code in ASP.NET/MVC/Core will be great.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Python in between. You need to setup a webhook out of Jira to airflow for example.

Webhook Configuration in your Jira like:

```
curl -X POST \\
     https://{airflow.SERVER}/api/v1/dags/{dag_name}/dagRuns \\
       -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \\
       -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \\
       -H 'Authorization: Basic *****************' \\
       -d '{"conf":{"ticket":"{{issue.key}}"}}'
```

Then host your code there and set up the connection to Jira and your DocuSign.

The code could look like the following:

```
atc_conn = JiraHook("jira").get_conn()

jql = "project =...."
issues = atc_conn.search_issues(jql, fields=["attachment"])

for issue in issues:

        attachments = issue.fields.attachment 

        for attachment in attachments:
            attachments_to_sign = attachment.get()
```

....